# Angular2-meteor load javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular

I use the Angular2-meteor framework but I have a problem when a try to load my javascript file.

Meteor load every file in seem time in a want to my js file loading after the html.

where I have to place the js file for playback after the html code

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Meteor are you using ? If you're using 1.3 , you can put the js files in a special directory named "imports" within your app. Files placed in this directory are not loaded by default and have to be imported using import statement. You can find more details at meteor docs : 
[Meteor Special Directories](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories)

As far as executing code is concerned, you can use the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook of the component. It is triggered once the component's view is fully initialized.

```
import {AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'
```

Then in your Component Class :

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      ngAfterViewInit() {
         // Your code here
      }
}
```